# Battery voltage compatibility

Tags: batteries

The original Li-ion battery in my camera has a voltage rating of 7v. Can an aftermarket battery with a 7.4v rating be safely used in my camera?

Comment: Yes (if it fits).

Comment: LiIon cells arte usually rated at a nominal 3.6 or 3.7V = 7.2 or 7.4 vpolts for 2 in series.  As the actual range during operation is about 3V to 4.2V per cell, labelling a 2 cell battery as 7V or 7.2V or 7.4V  is just a marketing decisions and IF it is LiIon all will will work much the same. Of more importance is that a higher true capacity battery will take longer to charge and/but will be somewhat overcharged by the original charger for technical reasons,

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that the camera manufacturer simply chose not to include the fractional voltage in the battery rating.

Older Li-Ion batteries are 3.6V nominal with a max charge voltage of 4.1 Vdc.

Newer Li-Ion and Li-Poly batteries are 3.7V nominal with a max charge voltage of 4.2 Vdc.

Your original battery most likely has 2 Li-Ion cells in series to make a nominal voltage of 7.2V.

Note that you may want to use an after-market charger if you are replacing the battery with a modern equivalent.  The new battery won't be damaged by the old charger but it may not exhibit the full capacity because it doesn't become fully charged.